# How can I get HTML element with jQuery through a variable?

Tags: jquery

Sometimes I run in to situations where I have the ID of a HTML element in a variable.
For example  `var activePage = frontPage`. How can I use this to get the DIV element with jQuery?

Because this is not working: `var div = $('#'+activePage+'footer li a')`.

I know I can use `document.getElementById(activePage)` - but I don't know how I can use this together with jQuery.

Comment: You need a space in there. `var div = $('#'+activePage+' footer li a')`. Without the space, jQuery looks for the ID of  `frontPagefooter`

Comment: yeah - it was the missing space.... * feeling stupid * :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a space in there. `var div = $('#'+activePage+' footer li a')`. Without the space, jQuery looks for the ID of `frontPagefooter`